# Tikz, put part of text into boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning. I try to get the following figure using Tikz environment.  I was thinking of using `\node` but the problems are the labels (Box A and Box B) and the numbers outside of boxes.

[image]

Comment: Could you make a minimal working example?

Comment: Search `\matrix` in the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `matrix` node and two `fit` nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes]
{1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
};

\node[draw=blue, thick, inner sep=2pt, fit=(A-6-3.north west) (A-9-5.south east)] (BB) {};
\node[draw=red, thick, inner sep=2pt, fit=(A-4-2.north west) (BB.south east)] (BA) {};

\node[red, right= 0mm of BA.north east] (LA) {Box A};
\node[blue] at (BB-|LA) {Box B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much... I'll study the matrix command